# React router v6: nested routes vs descendants routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was going through the latest version of the react-router-dom library i.e. v6. I want to understand what could be the specific use cases where I want to choose Descendant Routes over the Nested Routes. And vice versa.

One difference is that you don't need the Outlet component while using descendant routes. Is there any other aspect which differentiates the two? or just the Syntactic sugar to achieve the same?